# Change layout and styling for most recent post in CPT archive template

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called 'Blog' with an archive template of archive-su_blog.php. Within the template i am just calling the standard loop to pull in all the posts and then using some html to construct the page.

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the html and style for the most recent post? Rather than having the same html for all. I know how to do this with a custom query but i'm curious if there's a way to do it with the standard loop?

Example of what i would like to do with the standard `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` loop.

```
<div class="featured-post">
<div class="col-sm-6 featured-img"><img src=""></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 featured-info"> </div>
</div>

<div class="default-post">
<div class="post-info"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean the most recent post in a list of recent posts? That is, on the archive, there's X posts, and this one (at the top, presumably), is the most recent? There is a way - set a counter, and conditionally load a [template part](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/9978/11704) - if `0 === $counter++` then load your "custom" template part, otherwise load the "regular" template part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Query Arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('blog'),
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $i = 0;
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        if($i ==0){
            // My Custom style
            $query->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="featured-post">
            <div class="col-sm-6 featured-img"><img src=""></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 featured-info"> </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            // End of my Custom style
            $i++;
        }else{
            $query->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="default-post">
            <div class="post-info"></div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }           
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```